# how to put dynamic button in android useing its position

Tags: android

How to put dynamic button using xml.
i want to fetch the position of button from the xml and place them in screen.

Comment: http://sree.cc/google/android/dynamically-add-controls-in-android ... this was the first Google result for 'How to put dynamic button in android?????'

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by dynamic?

create an xml file called filename.xml, put this in. Change the drawables where necessary. That is bt_return and bt_returnpress

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bt_return" android:state_pressed="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bt_returnpress" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bt_return" android:state_focused="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bt_returnpress" android:state_focused="true" />
</selector>
```

Then assign the filename.xml to the background of the dynamic button u want.

Comment: ok..i have position of button in xml file.so how would be call ?

Comment: no, the above is a drawable. You put it in the drawable folder. And then in your layout, in the button you want you set the background to the drawable.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong you want to add a button dynamically in your view pragmatically?

If you have to get the parent view in which you want to add button, then create a button and add.

For example you have a LinearLayout already defined.

> LinearLayout controls =
>   (android.widget.LinearLayout)
>   findViewById(R.id.id_of_your_layout);
>
> Button button = new Button(context);
>
> controls.add(button);

that's it.

Answer (score 0):

In your xml layout file:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layoutbase"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Then in your code:

```
LinearLayout layoutbase =
    (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutbase);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams mylayout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

Button mybutton = new Button(this);
mybutton.setText("Button!");
mybutton.setTag("mybutton");
mybutton.setId(999);
mybutton.setLayoutParams(mylayout);
mybutton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

You also need to implement the OnClickListener:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String tag = (String) v.getTag();
    if (tag == "mybutton") {
        // do some stuff
    }
}
```

OR

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case 999:
        // do some stuff
        break;
    default:
    }
}
```